# Switch Case Looping PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, switch-statement

i was very frustated, i've tried many method but didn't find my expexted result. I have this data in my table database:

```
|       PartID         |   HasilProduksi  |QtyProduksi|
|----------------------|------------------|-----------|
|  BLAP-FG152-PF-KGX   |   Repair         |    1      |
|  AWDX-FG002-HN-KGX   |   Reject         |   90      |
|  HMXX-FG022-EG-KGX   |   Good           |  100      |
|  ECJX-FG018-AV-MCM   |   Good           |  111      |
```

and i want to create report with result :

```
|                      |    ACTUAL            |
|       PartID         | ---------------------|
|                      |Good | Repair | Reject|
|----------------------|-----|--------|-------|
|  BLAP-FG152-PF-KGX   |  0  |    1   |   0   |
|  AWDX-FG002-HN-KGX   |  0  |    0   |   90  |
|  HMXX-FG022-EG-KGX   | 100 |    0   |   0   |
|  ECJX-FG018-AV-MCM   | 111 |    0   |   0   |
```

and i'm using **switch case** method but the result is not like with my expected result. And This is my code :

```
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM $db_dthp WHERE IdBukti='$id_bukti'";
$qc = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlc);
$c = 0; $good=0; $reject=0; $repair=0;
while ($rc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qc)) {
    switch ($rc['HasilProduksi']) {
      case 'Good':

        $good += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        $datagood += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        break;
      case 'Reject':
        $reject += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        $datareject += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        break;
      case 'Repair':
        $repair += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        $datarepair += (int) $rc['QtyProduksi'];
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    $c++;
  }
$res['result'][$i]['data'][$b]['hp'][0]['good'] = number_format($good,0,'.','.'); 
$res['result'][$i]['data'][$b]['hp'][0]['reject'] = number_format($reject,0,'.','.'); 
$res['result'][$i]['data'][$b]['hp'][0]['repair'] = number_format($repair,0,'.','.');
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this other query, you will have already your data and you don't need the switch in php. You will do the case in your query:

```
$sqlc="SELECT PartID,
    CASE 
        WHEN HasilProduksi='Good' THEN QtyProduksi ELSE 0
    END as Good,
    CASE 
        WHEN HasilProduksi='Repair' THEN QtyProduksi ELSE 0
    END as Repair,
    CASE 
        WHEN HasilProduksi='Reject' THEN QtyProduksi ELSE 0
    END as Reject
FROM $db_dthp WHERE IdBukti='$id_bukti';"
```

Comment: thakyou you are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql if to do this

```
SELECT PartID,IF(HasilProduksi ='Good',QtyProduksi,0)as 
GOOD,IF(HasilProduksi ='Repair',QtyProduksi,0)as REPAIR,
IF(HasilProduksi ='Reject',QtyProduksi,0)as REJECT FROM 
$db_dthp group by PartID
```